# Extra RAM usage after changing SKScenes in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I'm creating a game in Swift using SpriteKit.

And after testing a lot, i checked in the Debug Navigator where it shows the CPU Usage, RAM, Energy, etc and saw that my game starts to use a lot more RAM after i change from Scene to Scene (i.e: game scene->main menu scene->game scene->main menu scene)

I don't know what is using so much RAM to be honest. A week ago, i remember all my game was using was 34-40MB RAM max in the beginning. Now starts at 140-150 and ends up at 180MB.

After moving from one scene to another, adds like 80-90MB usage each time. After switching several times, ended up having 920MB RAM used total in the app. I couldn't believe it.

The way i'm changing from scene to another scene is this:

```
        if let view = view {
            let transition = SKTransition.pushWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 0.5)
            let scene = MenuScene(size: view.bounds.size)
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

            view.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
```

If gameScene would be `GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)`

Am I doing something wrong? how can I know what's eating so much RAM in my game? Please need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I started using removeAllActions() when the scene transitioned, try that. I saw a difference.

Comment: @JozemiteApps where do i add that?

Comment: I put it before the view.presentScene.

Comment: Yes, that helped :) but i noticed that my sounds were taking a lot of RAM memory. :O especially my music in the main menu

Comment: sounds to me like your scenes are not being released,  simple test is to override deinit and doing a print to see if it is getting released

Comment: override deinit? can you give me an example? another thing i saw that i should be doing to reduce memory usage is to pre-load all my SKTextureNodes and Atlases maybe? is there any good example on how to do that? that might help... although my game is quite simple, i could save some laggy hickups or save some memory usage. Is 60-65MB RAM usage bad for a simple game?

Comment: ....  (SMH)  `deinit{print("Title has deinit")}`   Preloading will not reduce size,  that just loads the textures at an earlier time when needed, since the time you may need it is in a critical time spot.  Now if you are using SKTexture(imageNamed) then that creates a new texture every time, you may want to switch to Atlases for that (Use a tutorial not SO to get that how-to)  Do not worry about the actual number you are getting ram wise,  only worry about whether or not it grows in size.  The OS has a pretty good way of handling memory between apps.

Comment: Thanks for that comment. I managed to make a TextureManager class that will preload all my current textures as SKTextures inside a dictionary. Then whenever i need to create the SKSpriteNodes i do the following self.background = SKSpriteNode(texture: TextureManager.sharedInstance.getTexture(withName: "skybox")) is that properly done? I'm doing tho what you said, creating SKTexture with imageNamed like this: self.addTexture(withName: "1up", texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "1up"))

Comment: Also, right now i see that my game goes up to max 70mb but it won't grow more than that... starts at menu with 54mb and when playing goes up to 62-65mb, grows overtime a little up to 69-70 (i got to know why it's growing like that within the game)

Comment: Wow,  you wrote your own class, just use SKTextureAtlas

Comment: But isn't SKTextureAtlas meant only for sprite animations ?